# Portable storage that handles for file size greater than 4GB

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, exfat

I have to frequently copy paste files that are greater than 4GB. With marshmallow, we have to either stick to vFAT/FAT32 to use as portable or use it as internal storage. Is it possible to mount exFAT/NTFS/ext3/ext4 in the rooted marshmallow and use it as regular sdcard that is capable of handling max file size restriction?

Comment: Depending on the kernel, you are able to use exFAT formatted storage without any problems. Samsung supports this for example and many modern high capacity storages come preformatted that way (like my 64GB USB stick).

Comment: Motorola Moto g3 isn't currently able to handle exfat in marshmallow while it did back in lollipop. May be other phones are not able to use exfat formatted cards after marshmallow upgrade

Comment: As I already wrote: It depends on the kernel. My SIII LTE did not handle exFAT or NTFS without a custom kernel. My S6 Edge handles exFAT but not NTFS.

Comment: On Marshmallow you can add the SD card as adopted storage, making part of internal storage... This formats it as ext4 which would support the larger file size, but you can't take it out and copy to it since it's encrypted, you would have to copy it via USB, but it should support your larger file size requirements.